# How to align middle slash image with links?

Tags: html, css

I have this css code http://jsfiddle.net/989Pd/ where the slash images must be in the middle of text height. How can I do it?

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="pedio940">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Αρχική</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Προσθήκη RSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Επικοινωνία</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the slash as a background image, create it as an inline element and use the CSS: `vertical-align:middle`.

```
.menu ul li:after {
   content:url("http://i.imgur.com/uB4Gz.png");
   display:inline;
   vertical-align:middle
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/989Pd/8/

**Edit**: Yours is on the left, mine is on the right. I've drawn red lines to show the difference. They are not the same.

[image]

Comment: It seems the same to me.. tested on opera and chrome

Comment: @fiogkos They are not the same. I've edited my answer to show that. Your downvotes without additional information are not encouraging people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just adjust the height of the `li`

http://jsfiddle.net/989Pd/3/

Comment: And which browser is it not working in?  I fail to see how that's grounds for a downvote.

Answer (score -1):

put in a top value for the background like this: http://jsfiddle.net/989Pd/9/